# Try to make a function that will identify players and add two players' cards to left or right side

Tags: python-3.x, list, insert, append

An empty list is given, and I am trying to make a function which will identify player so that player1's cards will be added to left side of the empty list, and player2's cards will be added to right side of the empty list.
Right now I have this function:

```
class OnTable:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__cards = []

    def place(self,player,card):

        if player == 'player2':
            self.__cards.append(card)

        elif player == 'player1':
            self.__cards.insert(0,card)

    def __str__(self):

        list1 = '['
        for item in self.__cards:
            list1 += (str(item)+' ')

        list1 = re.sub(' ', ' ', list1.strip())

        return list1 + ']'
```

however, after I run this function using :

```
table = Ontable()
table.place(player1,card)
```

if only given me back an empty list...with nothing inside, is there a way I can let function know who is the player?
Thanks you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`table.place(player1,card)` Should be changed to `table.place('player1','Ace of Hearts')`. Player 1 should be a string according to your place function.